# How to remove a reference to the missing Microsoft Excel addin?

Tags: microsoft-excel

After an old version of Visual Studio was uninstalled from my computer I started getting following message every time I start MS Excel:

```
Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.LoadTestExcelAddIn.vsto'.
```

It makes sense and I would like to remove the reference to that add-in from my Excel (I don't need it) but I am not able to figure out how to do it.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: This is going to be a tough one I think.  The code to uninstall this plugin is actually stored in the file that is missing.  Normally, I would suggest `"VSTOInstaller.exe /uninstall [.vsto file path]"` but the file isn't there to call.  If @Gaussianiks suggestion doesn't work.. I would use [this page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/registry-entries-for-vsto-add-ins?view=vs-2022) for reference and hand remove your plugin.  Try again..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should likely have to remove it from your Excel COM Add-ins.

Following [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/169213/remove-excel-com-add-in-permanently.html):

> 1. Open Excel, go to File >Options>Add-Ins.
> 2. In the Manage box, click COM Add-ins, and then click Go. The COM Add-Ins dialog box appears.
> 3. Then click the COM add-in’s name that you want to delete in the Add-ins available box, and then click Remove.