# How to remove reference to disabled 3rd party Excel Add-ins (NOT COM add-ins!) from menu

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

This is for Excel 2016.

I did find [this](https://superuser.com/q/1687612/1140637) amongst a hundred other web results regarding the removal of COM add-ins, which I figured for myself, there's a handy remove button right in the menu:

[image: COM Add-ins button on developer tab]

[image: COM Add-ins menu featuring remove button]

However, there is no such button for the "Excel Add-ins" menu, the button for which is adjacent to the COM Add-ins button:

[image: Excel Add-ins menu next to developer tab ribbon button]

I can deselect it of course but that doesn't remove it from the list, even after restarting Excel.

So, how do I get rid of them?

if it helps, these were/are `.xla` add-in files on a shared drive, so I can't just delete them.

Comment: The Help article, which opens by clicking the "?" (in your screenshot at the top right) contains a lot of text that doesn't answer your question?

Comment: No, unfortunately. The help article is largely reflective of newer versions of Excel and suggested *uninstalling the entire add-in from my machine* which is simply not an option. I assume *somewhere* in Excel's local/user config there's a list of what appears that I could go hand edit, but I don't know where to begin looking.

Comment: Try [ShellExView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) and [ShellMenuView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shell_menu_view.html). Question: Is this for the Excel context-menu or the Windows context-menu?

Comment: This isn't related to context menus at all @harrymc

Comment: From the following link my guess is you have to do something with the registry, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/excel-com-add-ins-and-automation-add-ins-91f5ff06-0c9c-b98e-06e9-3657964eec72

Comment: You should call this a "list", not "menu". How did you disable the add-in?

Comment: Strictly speaking the term should likely be "dialog" or something, but considering the inclusion of illustrative screenshots I didn't imagine it would be possible to get confused! Haha. To disable the add-ins I just unchecked the box, as seen, all those starting "CODA" in my case. However even after closing everything and restarting Excel, they remain in the list to be enabled in future. Obviously that's expected behaviour, but I don't see a route to remove them from that list completely (not just disabled/unchecked: removed)

Comment: @gns100 Ahaha!! Thank you! I found this particular set of add-ins to have hidden themselves here: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options` with keys named `OPEN`, `OPEN1`, `OPEN2` etc. amongst a bunch of other options! The day is saved (post it as an answer?)